# NSTrackingArea works weird - Entire View, or nothing... no rectangles respected

Tags: cocoa, macos

In my "InitWithFrame" method of a view I'm setting a tracking area for which I want to capture mouse enter/exit events.
My problems are two fold:

1. Without NSTrackingInVisibleRect the events won't be called at all.
2. No matter what "rect" I put it, one that covers the entire view's frame or one that occupies just a small portion of it - the mouse enter/exited events are called for the entire view, regardless of where the mouse cursor is on the view.

this is how I initialize the tracking area:

```
trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:rect
  options: (NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingInVisibleRect | NSTrackingActiveAlways )
  owner:self userInfo:nil];
[self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
```

Any clues why this happens? I want the mouse enter/exit events to be called only for a small portion (the bottom part) of my view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mike Abdullah's answer explains point 2.

Here is a guess about why you don't receive events at all when not using the NSTrackingInVisibleRect flag:
Probably the variable `rect` you provide is not within the view's coordinate system.  You could use the following code as the designated initializer of your NSView subclass to receive `mouseEntered:` and `mouseExited:` events for the whole area of your view:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame 
{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) 
    {
        //by using [self bounds] we get our internal origin (0, 0)
        NSTrackingArea* trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:[self bounds] options:(NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveAlways) owner:self userInfo:nil];
        [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
        [trackingArea release];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTrackingArea_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004587-RH2-6949) says:

> When creating a tracking-area object,
>   you specify a rectangle (in the view’s
>   coordinate system), ...

Comment: Worth pointing out: `[self frame]` is in *the superview's* coordinate system, so passing `[self frame]` as the rectangle is very likely to be completely wrong: Most probably, the tracking rectangle will be as far up and right “in” your view as your view is up and right in its superview. The correct rectangle for the entire view, as shown in this answer, is `[self bounds]`. A view's bounds is within (and, indeed, the bounds of) its own coordinate system.

Comment: Good answer. Pretty sure you should `[trackingArea release]` after `[self addTrackingArea:trackingArea]`, it'll be owned by the view.

Answer (score 4):

Straight from the docs for `NSTrackingInVisibleRect`:

> The `NSTrackingArea` object is automatically synchronized with changes in the view’s visible area (`visibleRect`) and the value returned from `rect` is ignored.

Comment: thanks. that helped and i'm now getting the callbacks I need.

Comment: It however seems to work weirdly when this option is given for NSTrackingArea objects in each row of a view based NSOutlineView when it is scrolled. I had to implement as given at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9107224/804616 for it to work which must not be required since the docs say "syncrhonized with changes in the view's visible area".