# NSTrackingArea in tableview issue

Tags: cocoa, row, nstableview, nstrackingarea

I have set up my table view to work kinda like the Twitter app meaning when you hover over each row icons will appear on the right side and when leaving the row they will disappear.  I coded it based upon this:

[mouseExited isn't called when mouse leaves trackingArea while scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979639/mouseexited-isnt-called-when-mouse-leaves-trackingarea-while-scrolling)

The very strange thing is I have a checkbox on each row (along with other text fields, etc.) and when clicking the checkbox it causes the icons for that row to jump to the next row.  Clicking the checkbox again will cause them to jump to the next row.  This repeats until the icons jump to the last visible row then they will jump to the first visible row and keep repeating this behavior.  And it happens only sometimes. :-/  I tried to figure this out but nothing is even being called when this happens meaning no call to tracking areas or mouse entered/exited nothing.  Does this make any sense at all and maybe considering I'm trying to recreate how Twitter does it did I code it wrong?

Thanks,

rc

Comment: Some code, maybe? How are you inserting the icons into ecah row?

Comment: Yeah some code would help :-) The icons are actually buttons with an image. Then normally when hovering over a row I would call [[button animator] setAlphaValue:1] or to make it fade out [[button animator] setAlphaValue:0]. So the buttons are there all along I just set the alpha value in Xcode to 0 before launch so that I can fade them in/out later. I also get a notification in my controller when the user scrolls and automatically set the buttons to alpha 0 so it doesn't get messy. It's just this strange thing with the checkboxes that I haven't figured out. Let me know if you need more thanks!

Comment: More info...I know now that the issue is happening when I reload my table view. And the reason I reload my table view after clicking my checkboxes is to update my group row text (for example - 10 items selected).  When reloading my table view there is no message sent to my buttons because they are connected to my tablecellview class in the .xib. I am trying to find out where in my code I could cause this behavior but so far I have not been able to track it down? Thanks again...